# react useEffect clean up function

Tags: reactjs

I have post component where I have useEffect in which photo is set inside state. If I click to other links to fast I get error "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component." So it tells that I need to clean up, but no matter what I try to read online I cant figure out how to do cleaning properly and still get same error. This is what I have now.

```js
const ignore = useRef(true);
const [postImage, setPostImage] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    if (ignore) {
      if (postPhoto) {
        storageRef
          .child(postPhoto)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            setPostImage(url);
          });
      }
    }

    if (pathname === "/profile" || pathname === `/profile/${params.user}`) {
      setShow(false);
    } else {
      setShow(true);
    }
    return () => (ignore.current = false);
  }, [postData]);
```

How should clean up look like? It is something that I struggle to understand the most in past weeks.

Comment: Your variable name seems backwards - you want to ignore the data WHEN your component unmounts. I'd rename `ignore` to `unmounted` and set it to `true` in the cleanup function. You need to stop ALL state changes, so you also need to check for `unmount` inside` of your `.then` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `setPostImage(url)` runs when component is unmounted. To avoid this error check if `ignore.current` is `true` before updating the state:

```
storageRef
       .child(postPhoto)
       .getDownloadURL()
       .then((url) => {
          if(ignore.current) setPostImage(url); //--> here
       });
```

Comment: So I only want to clean up the state? And I don't stop functions running inside of useEffect with cleanup?

Comment: yes, do the check inside the then block because it is possible that getDownloadURL() is not resolved during the unmount process.